# Java get method from generic Class object

Tags: java, function, class, generics, types

I have a method like the following where this class holds a list of objects that as of now 2 different classes can be passed in.

```
public class DataTableEntity {
 List<Objects> objectContainer;

 public void setLinks(Class cls){
 for(Object obj : objectContainer){
  //the cls variable will hold what type of object it is 
  //so I need to somehow say if its a 'dog' then the obj I am going through is a dog
  // and the method is dog.getName else it might be cat and cat.getCatName etc.
 }
}
```

This function gets told what the List specifically are and then should format a property of the objects in that list correctly before being sent out to the client.  The different objects have different setter and getter names for these properties.  So I need to somehow take the generic Class object, see what kind of class it really is so I can then know what method, ".getAbc/.setAbc" or ".getXyz/.setXyz" to use.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you maybe show more code, because from your question i cant really understand what you are trying to do. but its probably possible and simple

Comment: basically I just have the above function in a class, that class has a property of List<Objects> that we use as a container to send via JSON to the web client this container uses just Objects as say a class of Dog or Cat can be put in the List<Objects> in order to be passed by JSON.  However one of the properties needs to be altered say Dog.name, from "Fido" to "<a>Fido</a>" and the same for cat, however its called say Cat.catName instead of Cat.Name. So I need to somehow be able to go through the containers List<Objects> and determine what they are so I know which property to format then

Comment: change it from a generic <object> into a Cat or Dog so I can call the Dog.setName or Cat.setCatName on all the <objects> in List<objects>

Comment: check the type of the object with `instanceof` and then cast to the class: `if(obj instanceof Cat) { Cat c = (Cat)obj; c.catName = "abc"; }` . but why does you function take `Class` as argument? it should be `Object`. `Class` is for Reflection and you dont need that here

Comment: ah....yea that would work lol I kind of got stuck in the wrong mindset for what I was trying to do as originally I was trying something else and this had a slightly different purpose. Thanks.

Comment: ooooh now I remember why I didn't want to just use the instance of... then cast it, because I didnt want to have to do a case statement of like "if dog, cat, fish etc" for each time I need to call a method on the object.

Comment: well, then you need a common interface. but that would mean that you have a function that has the same name and arguments in every class. what exactly are you setting for the different classes? example code that really shows what you are trying to do would help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this ?

```
public class DataTableEntity {
    List<Objects> objectContainer;

    // The Objects know already which Class they are, no need to pass it
    public void setLinks() {
        for(Object obj : objectContainer) {
            if(obj instanceof ClassA) {
                ClassA a = (ClassA)obj;
                a.doSomething();
            }
            else if(obj instanceof ClassB) {
                ClassB b = (ClassB)obj;
                b.doSomethingElse();
            }
            // and so on ...
        }
    }
}
```

a common Inteface would make the code better, because you wouldnt have to check for all the different Classes. But i dont know if that is possible for your case

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of **instanceof** statement?

It allows you to check if an object is an instance of a class, or its subclasses, and returns a boolean.

Like:

```
anyObject instanceof Object       // return true

integerObject instanceof Integer  // return true

integerObject instanceof Number   // return true

integerObject instanceof Double   // return false
```